# Recursion func w/o recursion

Tags: recursion

```
    function findNum(a, b) {
       if (!b) {
            b = 0;
       }
       if (a < 2) {
            throw new Error('wrong');
       }
       if (a === 2) {
           return 1 / a + b;
       }
       return findNum(a - 1, b + 1 / (a * (a -1)));
       }
```

Is there any way to write this func w/o recursion and without using while in it?

Comment: That isn't valid C++ code to begin with. But you can often turn recursion into a loop, where is your own attempt?

Comment: @UnholySheep that's is just given code and I have to propose a solution w/o recursion. I.e. my prof didn't give me any code, but the main thing is to find a way where we don't use recursion

Comment: Okay, but where is your own attempt at replacing the recursion with a loop? And explaining what the problem with your own attempt is

Comment: @Scheff'sCat sry, just updated